# WPF: How to create a collection that can be bound to

Tags: wpf

My app has a background thread that periodically retrieves data from an external source, in the form of key/value pairs. I would like to expose this data for binding, presumably by storing them in some kind of static(?) model, as the data will be needed by numerous views throughout my app. There are potentially hundreds of these keys, and may be different for each customer, so I can't simply create an INotifyPropertyChanged model with a property for each value.

The app has multiple views visible at any one time, and each of these will have numerous controls (usually textboxes) that I want to bind to individual items in the above collection. When a value in the collection is updated, any controls bound to *only* that item should change to reflect the new value. I'm assuming an `ObservableCollection` wouldn't be suitable here, as a change to a single item will result in all controls updating, regardless of which item they are bound to?

To throw a further complexity into the mix, some values (which are numeric) will need formatting for display, e.g. number of decimal places, or adding a suffix such as "volts". The formatting rules are user-defined so I can't hardcode them into (say) the XAML binding's `StringFormat` expression. Ideally I should be able to access both the raw value (e.g. for calculations), and the formatted version (for display purposes). I'm sure it must be possible to achieve the latter using some clever WPF feature!

I would appreciate any pointers on how I can solve these requirements.

**Edit**: it's worth mentioning that I've previously tried implementing the model as some kind of collection. The problem is that it won't be initially populated with all values, and these only get added some time later. When they *do* eventually get added, a bound control doesn't update - presumably because it wasn't initially able to bind to the missing value.

Comment: Static model is usually a bad idea, singleton is better. What are the types of your keys/values ? ObservableCollection only raises the CollectionChanged event when elements are added / suppressed, not when a particular element is modified. Each element has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged if you want to be aware of that. Finally, if you have different questions, please create different threads (cf. paragraph "To throw a further complexity..").

Comment: Create your own Converter which you use on your Bindings to format the data as you want. You can use a ConverterParameter to pass something to the Converter to give it a hint as to how to format the data i.e. the rule (which is in your ViewModel somewhere). Haven't got a clear picture of how you want the views to update.

Comment: @franssu the keys will be strings and the values doubles. In light of your comment, I guess I could use a dictionary, but instead of the value being a double type I'll use a class that has a double property and implements INPC (feels strange having a class with one property!). And apologies for my second question above, I thought it might be relevant to finding a solution to the model design.

Comment: @AndrewStephens I don't get why you say you "can't simply create an INotifyPropertyChanged model with a property for each value". Hundreds of elements is not really a lot ?! I would not use a dictionnary but something like an ObservableCollection<SomeKindOfTupleClassWhichImplementINPC<key, value>>.

Comment: @franssu the data being retrieved will differ for each customer of our product. I can't create a class that exposes the item values as separate properties as I won't know what the item names are.Regarding using ObservableCollection, my concern here is that when adding a new item to the collection, it is going to cause all controls in all views to rebind? This could be quite an overhead given how many there will be.

Comment: @AndrewStephens Each data item isn't a <double, string> pair ?

Comment: I would still try ObservableCollection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ObservableCollection` is perfect here.  You should find that a standard `ItemsControl` bound to an `ObservableCollection` will only update the controls of the items that have changed, not every item in the collection.

This is the reason `ObservableCollection` exists - the events that it raises specifically identify items that have changed, so that the UI can handle them sensibly.

I've tested this locally with a small WPF app and it works fine.  Worth noting, though, that a virtualised items panel would probbaly appear to break this behaviour when it scrolls...

**EDIT:** rereading your question, you actually say "When a value in the collection is updated..."  If your collection contains instances of a class, and you update properties on the class, you don't even need `ObservableCollection` for this to work - you just need the class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 1):

I would take a different approach, namely a variation of [Event Aggregation](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html).  I would have a single class that manages the overall collection (probably a singleton class like franssu suggested), but instead of binding directly to the collection in that class you create smaller models that are more specific to the individual views.

When your main model receives a new item, it publishes an event, which is consumed by the smaller models who can inspect the new item and determine whether or not they should add that item to their internal collection (the one the individual views are bound to).  If it doesn't "belong" to their view, they can simply ignore the event.

You could use similar event publishing for updates to items and such, although if you're binding to the actual items you probably don't need that.

Answer (score 1):

Just implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` Interface and the `INotifyPropertyChanged` and you ll get a Collection like the ObservableCollection.

But rember if you select a Item from your Collection (as example a ObservableCollection) and you change that item your other controls won t update. So if you have a class Person in your Collection and you change the name of one person the other controls won t get the new name of the person.

Inside the Person object you still have to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` Interface and raise the event when your name changes.

So what I want to tell you is: A Collection with the interface `INotifyCollectionChanged` will only tell the bound controls: There is a new Item, there has been a item removed or a items index changed BUT not if the item itself changes.

**So you ll need a Collection that provides the points above and a Item contained by the collection that raises events if a property of it changes.**

Comment: So in my scenario, I'll have a couple of hundred controls (e.g. textboxes) bound to individual items in the collection, and a control will update when its underlying item changes. But what if I add a new item to the collection? will INotifyCollectionChanged cause *all* controls to rebind? I'm concerned about any performance overhead if this is the case.